# Muktika canon and Telugu anthology

Tags: scripture, upanishads

Wikipedia's many articles on Upanishads (e.g [Brahma Upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma_Upanishad), etc. many minor Upanishads) says:

> In the Telugu anthology of 108 Upanishads of the Muktika canon, narrated by Rama to Hanuman, this Upanishad is listed at number...

So, I just want to know Is the concept of Muktika canon originated from any Telugu anthology? or Which Telugu anthology constitutes this?

Comment: The Muktika canon comes from the Muktika Upanishad, which I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3012/36 The Muktika Upanishad is believed by many to be a later text, so perhaps it was created by some Telegu person.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I've also posted another [question](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9499/277) about it.