# Is Muktika Upanishad genuine?

Tags: upanishads

How can Muktika be genuine when it lists later day upanishads like Kali santarana ?

How can it list vedas which were revealed later, eg: Shukla yajur veda releaved during the end of Dwapara yuga much later after the period of Rama.

How come these names be listed in a text which is believed during that of Treta Yuga ?

The canon lists upanishads like Sharabha, Skanda ,Rama tapini, Seeta upanishad etc which are usually not found in the Vedas.

How come it mentions Suka (who lived in Dwapara yuga) ?

Further, in Ramayana is there any mention where Rama says about his knowledge or about following Vedanta ?

Comment: BTW im also trying to find about Chaitanya Upanishad which according to a speaker(Gaudiya) i was listening to is a branch of Yajur Veda. Any idea about it?

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande I am posting this because Keshwav Srinivas and some others have mentioned about this in some of the answers

Comment: ya thats ok. I'm genuinely asking you, you have any idea? I heard that this upanishad speaks about Divinity of Lord Chaitanya Mahaprabhu and His associates. Since I could not find any full fledged authentic Scriptural references, i was thinking if I could find this Upanishad it would be great.

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande all such upanishad are FAKE !

Comment: There is not any 100% proof method to determine whether a Upanishad is genuine or not. We can only say 'likely to be authentic' and 'likely to be unauthentic'.

Comment: @Tezz this is because many people are unaware of such things. For example Isha upanishad is said to be 40th chapter of shukla yajur Samhita. You can compare its style and language and chadnas etc to the claimed portion. Hence some people consider only 9 or 11 as genuine.

Comment: Related: [When did Rama tell Hanuman the Muktika Upanishad?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9499/277)

Comment: @Pandya Yes I have gone through that link but it does not talk of genuinity of the text

Comment: @RakeshJoshi If you know the answer, why don't you answer it?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Here many people have said of N number of upanishads so its important to ask this. Keshav has also mentioned this in many answers so i want to know that poit of view