# Muktika Upanishad

Tags: upanishads, nara-narayana

Narayana Upanishad listed as 18th out of 108 Upanishads in Muktika Upanishad which is discussion between Rama and Anjaneya.
In 4th chapter of Narayana Upanishad, it’s said as Narayana as Devaki putra, means Krishna, this event happened in Mahabharata.
As Ramayana happened before Mahabharata, how to relate both events?

Comment: Are you looking for answer that relies on yuga/manvantara/kalpa bheda theories or from purely historical basis (i.e., events narrated in Ramayana and Mahabharata happened only once)?

Comment: The same events repeat in different Kalpas in almost the same way.. so there is no contradiction.

Comment: This may be of your interest: [When did Rama tell Hanuman the Muktika Upanishad?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9499/277)

Answer (score 1):

This relates to the Hindu concept of time and creation. World is destroyed and recreated in cycles of chaturyugi, manvantar, kalpa &c. Apart from that, there are also parallel universes (multiverse) in which Dharmashastras are revealed from time to time untill they're lost again. So, Valmiki had written Ramayan before Lord Ram ever incarnated on Earth. Also, Vasisth told the the gist of Gita to a 16 year old Ram as it would have been recited to Arjun by Krishna, aeons before incarnation of Krishna. In simple terms, per Vedic theology, the sastrakaras are Trikalagya. Accordingly, your problem may be explained as such.

Cf.

1. Sriyogvasisthmaharamayan Sthiti Prakaran (cyclic time)
2. Sriyogvasisthmaharamayan Leelopakhyan (parallel universe)
3. Sriyogvasisthmaharamayan Nirvana Uttarardh (Bhavishya Geeta)

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Could you add authentic sources to support your answer? On HSE, Answers must be back up by sources. Visit [how-to-answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) section to learn more.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I've provided the citations.